# Printing nodes whose value is smaller than than the value set in the parameter

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I have this code which is supposed to take in a linked list and return the nodes which are lesser than the value of node specified in the parameter, but it is doing exact opposite. What I am doing wrong?

```
static LinkedListNode removeNodes(LinkedListNode list, int x) {
    LinkedListNode current = list;
    while(current.next != null ){
        if (current.val >x){
            if (current.next.next == null){
                break;
            }
            else{
            current = current.next.next;
            }
        }
        else{
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Should you be using `current.val < x` instead? If it is giving you all the ones you don't want.

Comment: **it is doing exact opposite** , seriously missing what **opposite** means in your context here, but apparently changing from **if(current.val > x)** to **if(current.val < x)** maybe means the **opposite** you are ;looking for??

Comment: @Chris the meaning behind **opposite** boiled to the **same** thing for both of us :)

Comment: Is it supposed to be filtering an existing list? 
Or returning the nodes which are smaller? 
There is a difference.

Comment: @Chris there are multiple errors apart from that comparison.

Comment: This feels like there is either additional code missing that calls this function, and tests, because reading the code, it seems to be that it doesn't function at all, as opposed to 'does the opposite'

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a node from the linked list, you need to change the .next reference instead of the current value.

Also your > x should be < x

```
static LinkedListNode removeNodes(LinkedListNode list, int x) {
    LinkedListNode current = list;
    while(current.next != null ){
        if (current.val < x){
            if (current.next.next == null){
                break;
            }
            else{
                current.next = current.next.next;
            }
        }
        else{
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```